# Run Jenkins job if another job ran at least once today

Tags: jenkins

I want to set up a Jenkins job (let's call it A) that would run nightly and check if another Jenkins job (let's call it B) ran successfully at least once today. I don't want B to trigger A because B may run multiple times per day, but I want A to run only once--and not to run at all if B did not run.

I thought of using the "Conditional step" option, but I'm not sure how to configure the condition. The only way I know of to examine the timestamps for another job's builds is via Jenkins restful API, but if I do it via curl commands in shell, I'd have to expose the Jenkins user's password, which I don't want to do (not to mention having to parse the json output in shell, which I would also rather avoid doing).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to expose the Jenkins users password as you could just pass it as a variable ( just set it in your global settings) you can access it via ${env.varName} I think... how many times a day does B run? And what would it mean if B failed at some point in the day? Would that mean A could run?

Comment: B can run zero or more times per day. A must run if and only if B ran at least once successfully. And yeah, I can hide the password in an env variable, but the command line for curl is echoed in the output log, where it lists the password in the clear. At any rate, I wonder why I should authenticate again via a remote restful API when I'm already running from inside a Jenkins instance. Is there an easier way to collect the information on the B's build timestamps?

Comment: Never seen the password in the output log, I'll keep an eye out for that.. at first glance it seems api is the way to go. Would you need to trawl through the time stamps, would an array of job build statuses suffice and if a success is in there then carry on?

Comment: Unfortunately, I would have to go through the timestamps, since the existing builds may be from yesterday, not today.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way but might work:

Make B write the date to a file F_B after B runs successfully.

Make A write the date to a file F_A after A runs.

Before A runs, check F_A and F_B, only make A run when F_A and F_B are different.

Now you can make B trigger A after B runs successfully.

Or maybe you can take a look at [jenkins FSTrigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/fstrigger)

Add a post build step to B (only when success), check the date in a file and change it only if the date is different from the data when this build finishes.

Add a FSTrigger to A and monitor that file.

Comment: Thanks. That would have worked. But we have Jenkins in a cloud (Cloudbees), where the jobs run on temporary instances, so keeping state like that, although possible, is a big pain.

Comment: So maybe you can set up a database somewhere and monitor the values in that database. This will cost more but also should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement such things nicely with the **[Script SCM plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+SCM+Plugin)**:

- you'd basically implement a SCM "polling" step for job "A" as a groovy script that checks whether job "B" did run successfully
- set the SCM polling interval for "A" to once/night then.

Comment: Thanks. That may work. I'll see if Cloudbees would provide the Script SCM plugin. But they would probably insist on every individual Groovy script being specially approved.