# Schedule Jenkins task for once per day, but only after successful run of other tasks

Tags: jenkins

I need to schedule a Jenkins task so it runs once per day, but only if certain other tasks succeed at least once that day. That situation makes it [similar to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636780/run-jenkins-job-if-another-job-ran-at-least-once-today), but none of the answers there describe how to deal with the contingencies I have.

My team has a Jenkins process that builds the software. We'll call that the Builder. Builder checks our GitHub repo every 15 minutes and runs if it sees a code change.

We have another task that runs simple tests. This entire test suite can finish in less than 15 minutes. This is the Short-Tests task. Short-Tests run every time Builder passes.

Lastly, we have a set of tests that take hours to run. Let's call these the Long-Tests. We want to run this once per day, but only if Builder and Short-Tests both pass. The Long-Tests start late at night so we can check the results the next morning.

Furthermore, we want to run Long-Tests only on the most recent successful build that day. *If the most recent build failed, we want Jenkins to ignore that build and test using a previous build that passed.*

If no builds pass that day, there is no need to run Long-Tests at all.

I can schedule Long-Tests for once per night like this, but please tell me how to set up the dependencies.

```
   01 00 * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this behavior you need some kind of persistence to flag successful build and successful short test completion. There are several options available depending on your actual setup such as:

- File based flag (writing to file on successful build / test)
- Database flag (writing to database on successful build / test)
- Git branch manipulation (pushing/merging to specific branch on successful build step, such as example given here: http://andrewtarry.com/jenkins_git_merges/).

Once you have your persistence setup, you can trigger builds either on change or periodically. For example following dependencies can be setup:

1. Push to Git code branch, triggers Jenkins Build job
2. For this step you need persistence, say pushing to git: Upon successful completion of build stage, short tests are triggered and, If successful, push to git "latest passing short test" branch is executed using Git Publisher plugin for example. This is to ensure that only last passed short test are going to be scheduled for long nightly tests.
3. Lastly, long tests are scheduled periodically, handling branch "latest passing short test".

This is just top level overview, since details depend a lot on your actual setup, permissions, git policies, type of Jenkins configuration etc.